Angular - "Invalid ICU message. Missing '}'.ngtsc(-995002)" error
In my Angular code, I use interpolation. But, it poses an error although the syntax is correct. (Angular v18.1.0, node v20.15.0, typescript v5.4.5, rxjs v7.8.1)
Here are code snippets from the same programme -
1.
 <ng-container matColumnDef="name"> <th style="width: auto" mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Name </th> <td style="width: auto" mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{ element.name }} </td> </ng-container>
This provides an error message near the opening braces of element.name (the error in the title).
2.
<ng-container matColumnDef="name"> <th style="width: auto" mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Name </th> <td style="width: auto" mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{ element.name }} </td> </ng-container>
This does not show an error.
I tried -

updating versions
handling version incompatibility between angular and typescript
linting - installing eslint (nothing happened)
uninstalling and reinstalling vs code
updating extensions
disabling and enabling extensions
debugging in vs code (no result)
uninstalling and reinstalling angular and typescript
Looking for errors in the console - no error reported

The output in localhost is perfect without error. but vs code keeps reporting this error.
When i copy and paste the same code with the error in a different file, that works correctly. and the same code with the error works well on another computer, but not mine.

These two snippets are literally the same string. You will need to do more research on your code on how the components are different.
